# SpEL in Spring Batch config file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

The context file I'm looking at has a bean definition. In the definition is sets one of the parameters with the following line.

```
<property name="processLimit" value="#{jobParameters['MAX.FILES.TO.PROCESS']}" />
```

I understand that this means that 'MAX.FILES.TO.PROCESS' is assigned a value somewhere in jobParameters.

I'm not sure where I would find the jobParameters file to examine it and see what the value is.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure where I would find the jobParameters file to examine it and see what the value is?

When you launch/start a Job then you can specify some job parameters that is needed for the Job and it will be picked by spring batch configuration automatically. You don't need any jobParameters file.

Please have a look at different method of **[JobParametersBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html)** to create required type of job parameter.

---

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BeansException,
        JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, BindException {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "config/application-context.xml");
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) appContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
    jobLauncher.run((Job) appContext.getBean("job_name"),
            new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("MAX.FILES.TO.PROCESS", 10L)
                    .toJobParameters());

}
```

OR

JUnit Test Sample

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/application-context.xml",
        "classpath:config/jobs.xml" })
public class AppTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void launchJob() throws Exception {

        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersBuilder.addLong("MAX.FILES.TO.PROCESS", 10L)
                .toJobParameters();

        // testing a job
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);

        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

    }
}
```